# 4-tiles main menu with borders between two adjacents ones

Tags: html, menu, onsen-ui

I'm trying to implement this simple main menu for my app using OnsenUI:

[image: layout]

(The external border is just to define the image boundaries)

I'm using this HTML code:

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-row style="border-bottom: solid #f9e8d5 2px; height: 50%;">
    <ons-col style="border-right: solid #f9e8d5 2px;">
        <span style="color:#a67c52;">FIND</span>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col style="border-left: solid 2px #f9e8d5;">
        <span style="color:#a67c52">MAP</span>
    </ons-col>           
  </ons-row>
  <ons-row style="border-bottom: solid #f9e8d5 2px; height: 50%;">
    <ons-col>
        <span style="color:#a67c52">FAVS</span>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col>
        <span style="color:#a67c52">UPLOAD</span>
    </ons-col>           
  </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

Everything is fine except for the fact that the border between A/B doesn't show up. Looking at firebug's inspector it seems like the custom styling gets stripped away from the final HTML.

I'm thinking about overriding the style of `.col` to achieve this result but that would mean putting an extra border on the right side of B.

Thank you very much in advance, I'm still a beginner in these kind of things...
3mpty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a css class to achieve what you want. You can find the complete code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ayokp).

Here is the HTML

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-row style="border-bottom: solid #f9e8d5 2px; height: 50%;">
    <ons-col>
        <span style="color:#a67c52;">FIND</span>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col class="left">
        <span style="color:#a67c52">MAP</span>
    </ons-col>           
  </ons-row>
  <ons-row style="border-bottom: solid #f9e8d5 2px; height: 50%;">
    <ons-col>
        <span style="color:#a67c52">FAVS</span>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col class="left">
        <span style="color:#a67c52">UPLOAD</span>
    </ons-col>           
  </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

Here is the css class you need

```
.left {
    border-left: solid 2px #f9e8d5;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, sometimes you just can't see the most straightforward solution :)